# Generate distribution from Maven project

Tags: java, maven, distribution

I want to build an application distribution with Maven. I have a module in my project which holds the main source code. I decided to build the application distribution from this module. I'm telling maven in the module's POM to copy all the configuration files and dependant libs to the `target/` directory. My problem is that Maven keeps all the build related temporary dirs (like. `classes`, `generated-sources`, `maven-archiver`) in the target directory. I wan't to auto delete these at least during the `install` phase. How can i achive this? If i put the `maven-clean-plugin` to the end of the build it looks like Maven always deletes the whole `target` directory, no matter who i'm trying to exclude files what i'm trying to keep.

Comment: Why do you want to delete these files? I assume it not to save a small amount of disk space. You can do a `mvn clean install` to ensure you are making a clean build each time.

Comment: Because it confuses developers who are trying to copy the distribution files from the target dir.

Comment: Perhaps you should be telling them not to do that.  The whole point of doing an `install` is to put the build in your repository and the whole point of the `deploy` command is to deploy the build to a shared area like a nexus server. This is what they should be using. Even maven doesn't look in the `target` area of other modules (it uses one of the two ways I have mentioned)  BTW You can `package` but not install if you don't want to touch the repository.

Comment: Deploying to remote Maven repository is fine. We already doing this. But what about production releases? I guess there are many projects which uses Maven for building and they are not just about artifacts but configuration files. So they have a file and directory structure which is needed for correct run. I do know now that i'm looking for something like the assembly plugin.

Comment: Assembly sounds like the right answer, esp for a client application.  I have also use Apache Karaf + iPOJO.  This uses a features file and configurations files to automatically download the right modules/versions from a nexus repo and load up components dynamically. It even supports upgrading and changing components while the application is running, even jars which contain native libraries. :P

Comment: Sounds interesting, i'll definitely check this out. Thanks for mentioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this in your pom

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2-beta-4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>user_distribution</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>attached</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/main/assembly/dist.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

and here is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.1.xsd">

    <id>dist</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <files>
        <file>
            <source>target/${pom.artifactId}-${pom.version}.jar</source>
            <outputDirectory>lib/</outputDirectory>
        </file>
    </files>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>directory to be included</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>file name to be included</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>another directory to be included</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

Comment: Looks nice. I'll try this out.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm telling maven in the module's POM to copy all the configuration
>   files and dependant libs to the target/ directory

How are you doing this?

Based on the question, it looks like you need to worry less about selectively deleting contents of target folder (which can be done by customizing [maven clean plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin)), but creating a distribution using [maven assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) (as pointed out by @Scorpion).

The latter allows you to bundle together all your project artifacts including the dependencies into zip or other formats, which can then be easily used by developers.  You may want to decouple this from regular build by using a separate `profile`, so that the distribution is built only on need basis.

Comment: "How are you doing this?" I'm configuring the `maven-dependency-plugin` with the `copy-dependencies` and `unpack` goals. See: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html and http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-mojo.html